# How to send a response only after a query has been executed in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a remote method in loopback like:

```
 Alerts.getAlertDetails = function (alertId, options, cb) {
        var response = {};
        var userId = options.accessToken.userId;
        Alerts.app.models.MobileUserAlertRelation.find({where: {userId: userId, alertId: alertId, isDeleted: -1}, include: {relation: 'alerts', scope: {include: ['alertTypes'], where: {status: 1}}}}, function (err, alertRel) {


            if (alertRel.length > 0 && alertRel[0].alerts()) {
                response.code = 200;
                response.status = "success";
                response.data = {};

                if (alertRel[0].alertId) {
                    response.data.alertId = alertRel[0].alertId;
                }
                if (alertRel[0].readStatus) {
                    response.data.readStatus = alertRel[0].readStatus;
                }
                if (alertRel[0].receivedOn) {
                    response.data.alertReceivedOn = alertRel[0].receivedOn;
                }

                var alertData = alertRel[0].alerts();
                if (alertData.title) {
                    response.data.alertTitle = alertData.title;
                }
                if (alertData.message) {
                    response.data.alertShortMessage = alertData.message;
                }
                if (alertData.extraMessage) {
                    response.data.alertMessage = alertData.extraMessage;
                }
                if (alertData.priority) {
                    response.data.alertPriority = alertData.priority;
                }
                if (alertData.validUntil) {
                    response.data.alertExpiresOn = alertData.validUntil;
                }
                if (alertData.images && alertData.images.length > 0) {
                    response.data.alertImages = [];
                    for (var image in alertData.images) {
                        if (alertData.images.hasOwnProperty(image)) {
                            response.data.alertImages.push(constants.ALERT_IMAGE_URL + '/' + alertData.images[image]);
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (alertData.alertTypes() && alertData.alertTypes().alertTypeName) {
                    response.data.alertType = alertData.alertTypes().alertTypeName;
                }

                if (alertData.alertLocations && alertData.alertLocations > 0) {
                    response.data.alertLocations = [];
                    response.data.policeDepartments = [];
                    response.data.hospitals = [];
                    response.data.fireDepartments = [];
                    var locations = alertData.alertLocations;
                    for (var locKey in locations) {
                        if (locations.hasOwnProperty(locKey)) {
                            if (locations[locKey].data) {
                                response.data.alertLocations.push(locations[locKey].data);

                                console.log(locations[locKey].data);
                                if (locations[locKey].data.type) {
                                    var locationType = locations[locKey].data.type;
                                    if (locationType === "Polygon") {
                                        var coordinates = locations[locKey].data.coordinates[0];
                                        var polygonCenter = getPolygonCenter(coordinates);
                                        console.log(polygonCenter);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                cb(null, response);
            } else {
                response.code = 404;
                response.status = 'error';
                response.message = 'Alert not found.';
                cb(null, response);
            }
        })
    };
```

But when I call this method through api, response is received without data added from the complex code part. I know that callback will be called asynchronously here and so that cb(response) will be called before the complex code is executed completely. How can i send response only after the complex part is completed and data is correctly added to response from that data. I cannot move cb(response) inside the complex part as data is being pushed in for loop. 
I have heard of promises, can it be used here, if so, how could it be done?
Someone please help!!

Comment: Can you try an [error first callback](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/)? Likely the response you are looking for is the second parameter in the callback, so if `res` is `null` that actually implies that no error occurred.

Comment: You need to do your loop in async. Please show some code for loop

Comment: @JustinHellreich I am already using error first callback. Sorry that I missed it in the sample code.

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani I will update question with code for loop.

Comment: You are passing a callback to `Model.find` which is not error first.

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani Code for loop somewhat looks like this. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Is any operations in loop async?

Comment: @JustinHellreich Sorry, I did'nt get you correctly. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `callback` should be `function` and `response.data` should be object not array

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani  Can you please check the code now. This is the full code, didnt post it since it was too long.

Comment: In `alertRel[0].alerts()`, is `alerts` a relation? what type relation?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani yes alerts is a relation, belongsTo relation.

Comment: The problem is that. I'll provide an answer

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of fetching relation in `if`.

The relation method is an async.

```
Alerts.getAlertDetails = function (alertId, options, cb) {
        var response = {};
        var userId = options.accessToken.userId;
        Alerts.app.models.MobileUserAlertRelation.find({where: {userId: userId, alertId: alertId, isDeleted: -1}, include: {relation: 'alerts', scope: {include: ['alertTypes'], where: {status: 1}}}}, function (err, alertRel) {

        if(alertRel.length < 1){
        return handleError();
        }

        alertRel[0].alerts(handleResponse);

        function handleResponse(err, alertRelAlert){
                if(err) return handleError();

                    if (alertRelAlert) {
                //all that code in question if if section
                }else {
                return handleError();
                }
        }

        function handleError(){
        response.code = 404;
                response.status = 'error';
                response.message = 'Alert not found.';
                cb(null, response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt, where will the success cb() be written here?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying it.

Comment: @DevStar The success part comes in `if (alertRelAlert) {...`. I commneted in code that you move it from the main code and I missed that for simplicity in answer

Comment: What should I do if I need another find query inside the loop?

Comment: @DevStar For such these situations [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a good option

Comment: Thanks for the info mate!